# Exit console application after it is done processing

Tags: c#, command-line, process, arguments

I have code that starts a process which contains 3 arguments separated by spaces.

```
 ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
 info.FileName = exeLauncher;
 info.Arguments = path + " " + exeName + " " + restartNeeded;
 Process process = new Process();
 Process.Start(info);
```

I'm parsing the arguments on the process that I start and does some processing.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Console.WriteLine(args[0]);
    Console.WriteLine(args[1]);
    Console.WriteLine(args[2]);

    //some more processing here

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

After processing, I would like the console window to close itself. I have tried using the `/c` argument like this but it just interprets it as a plain string.

```
info.Arguments = "/c" + path + " " + exeName + " " + restartNeeded;
```

I have also tried to enclose the arguments in `""` double quotes but it's not working.

```
info.Arguments = string.Format("/c \"{0} {1} {2}\"", path, exeName, restartNeeded);
```

Comment: why dont you remove the `Console.ReadLine();` which would close the console

Answer (score 2):

You can try it like this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Console.WriteLine(args[0]);
    Console.WriteLine(args[1]);
    Console.WriteLine(args[2]);

    //some more processing here

}
```

`Console.ReadLine();` will make you wait and the window will not be closed until you press the enter key. Thus You can remove this line to accomplish the task.

Answer (score 1):

did you try to remove `Console.ReadLine();` and return int to know if it executed with success, like:

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{

    Console.WriteLine(args[0]);
    Console.WriteLine(args[1]);
    Console.WriteLine(args[2]);

    //some more processing here

    return 0; // if success or > 1 for errors
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
Environment.Exit(0);
```